# Automatic sudo permissions for startup script

Tags: shell-script, shell, sudo, init-script, sysvinit

I need to run a script upon startup, which I understand needs to be done in the `init.d` folder. Now this script requires `sudo` permissions, it prompts the user for the sudo password when being run normally.

Is it possible to have my startup script run with sudo permissions automatically granted? Do I need to give the user password-less `sudo` permission? Ideally I'd have it run without any user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the system runs startup scripts with full root access by default, so you don't have to do anything.

Note that the script location depends on which `init` package is used in your system.

For classic SysVinit, the start-up scripts are usually located in `/etc/init.d` and symbolic links indicating their place in the startup/shutdown order are created in `/etc/rc<number>.d/` directories, where `<number>` indicates the runlevel your script is supposed to run on. (A runlevel is sort of "overall system state": on RedHat-style systems, the default runlevel is 5 if you have GUI login enabled, and 3 otherwise. On Debian-style systems, it tends to be 3 always.)

Updating the symbolic links in `/etc/rc<number>.d/` can be tedious, so there is often a tool that can do it for you. The most common such tool is `chkconfig`: it requires you to place some specially formatted comments at the beginning of your script (see `man chkconfig` for details appropriate to your distribution). Then you can just place your script into `/etc/init.d` and run `sudo chkconfig --add <your script name>`.

If your system uses a newer replacement for SysVinit, like `upstart` or `systemd`, they may include a SysVinit compatibility system so the above instructions may still apply; but you should consider learning the new ways too, since SysVinit is considered aged and less than optimal for modern multi-core systems.

Comment: I've looked into this and the two systems I have are Ubuntu 14.04 using upstart, and Ubuntu 16.04 using systemd. How can I tell if they have Sys V compatibility? Does that mean the OS would run scripts from both init systems?

Comment: Basically, if `/etc/init.d/` exists (and is populated by anything other than a README telling not to put scripts there any more), you can expect that the compatibility mechanism exists. Although competing init systems existed, SysVinit was *the standard solution* in the Unix world for such a long time that compatibility with it is not going to vanish overnight.